Exception thrown when trying to select a css ID containing "|"
The ID's of my controls are built with | symbols, but when trying to select the control in bunit with 'Find', it get's into an exception and fails to find the element.
Is there a special meaning to the | in css?

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php

Where is your code? Maybe you have id="foo|bar" and that has invalid character in HTML ID attribute. Check https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html 6.2 point

In an old spec I saw In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A1 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_).

Seems it's allowed in HTML5 though, just can't contain any spaces

It's valid html5 id, but if you try document.querySelector("#foo|bar") you'll get an exception, for example Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#foo|bar' is not a valid selector.

Well yeah because | is used for other purposed in CSS as seen in the linked URL

The questioner asks whether | has any meaning in CSS and I don’t know what that is (I’ve looked at @DarkBee link). Could someone explain?

See here? It's definitely not valid to use out of this scope as pointed out in this fiddle (tooltip image)

@AHaworth - In this case, a "vertical bar" character is a namespace separator. So a selector of foo|bar means a "bar" element in the namespace associated with the "foo" prefix. The association of the prefix with the namespace is done using the @namespace at-rule. There's not much call for it in styling HTML documents, but it's a useful feature for styling XML documents. See CSS Qualified Names for details.

Yes, the vertical pipe does have special meaning in CSS. You need to escape it inside an ID or class selector.


#foo|bar {
  color: blue;
}

#bar\|foo {
  color: red;
}
<div id="foo|bar">I am not blue</div>
<div id="bar|foo">I am red</div>



